# Android synchronize clock programmatically

Tags: android, root, system-clock

I'm developing an application that:
1. Runs in close network (no internet access).
2. All target devices have root permission.

I need to synchronized the device clock with my server clock each hour.
I found that I can't change default ntp server.

I'm planning to do that with web-service that returns server current timestamp and to change the time programmatically.

**Is there more common way to do that?**